# chsh: Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges

Tags: macos, shell, credentials, macos-highsierra

I am unable to change my default shell in osx high sierra.

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh username 
chsh: Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.  Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.
```

I looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/442849/why-do-i-see-operation-was-denied-because-the-current-credentials-do-not-have-t/446519) and there does not seem to be an updated answer:

Comment: OK, this may be a dumb question, but did you try it *without* the ``sudo``?  And leaving off the *username*?

Comment: Yes, I tried that a few times... I realized I am using iterm and it was super simple to setup in the preferences. Should have looked there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am unable to change my default shell in osx high sierra.

> I would like to add 2 important things here. These are applicable to
>   MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73) and probably some other recent and
>   upcoming versions of MacOS.
>
> 1. `chsh` is not enough to change the default shell. Make sure you
>      press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> while your terminal is open and change the "Shells
>      open with" option to "Default login shell."
> 2. In case of `bash`, make sure that you execute `echo $BASH_VERSION` to
>      confirm you are running the intended version of bash. `bash --version`
>      does not give you correct information.

Source [How to set my default shell on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119840/3536342), answer by [Tushar Vazirani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695804/tushar-vazirani)

Comment: Thanks, I realized I am using iterm not the default terminal client. I ended up setting this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276703/how-to-make-zsh-run-as-a-login-shell-on-mac-os-x-in-iterm  In iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles Tab -> General section set Command to: /bin/zsh --login and works great. Thanks for the quick response.